# Android GridLayout match_parent ignored (inner views don't strech)

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have a problem with GridLayout, I need it to be match_parent, with two columns, first column should stretch to fill as much space as possible, second column should be wrap content on the right side. This is my code:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/playlist_basic_info"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:text="Název"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        style="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Ikona"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        style="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:hint="Zadejte název playlistu"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/icon_playlist_world"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Here you can see how it looks:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make editext width to

```
  <EditText 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.8"
     android:hint="Zadejte název playlistu"/>
     <ImageButton
     android:src="@drawable/icon_playlist_world"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.2"
    />
```

Comment: Try adding weight as in the  answer

Comment: But I don't want to use weight, I want it wrap_content

Comment: So why don't you use a linear layout then

Comment: I have seen GridLayout used this way, so it must work somehow, with LinearLayout I would have to use more layouts than just one

Answer (score 0):

A TableLayout seems easier.

With GridLayout, you can align right like this :

```
<GridLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/playlist_basic_info"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="2"
android:orientation="horizontal" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<EditText
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Zadejte název playlistu" />

<TextView
    style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="Název"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_playlist_world" />

<TextView
    style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="Ikona"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</GridLayout>
```